# How to create a barrier feature class to use in a geometric network?

Tags: geometric-network, flow

I am working with the NHD and need to isolate stream segments upstream of barriers.  I have too many barriers (thousands) to do this manually using the Geometric Network barrier tool on the toolbar. How can I create a geometric network feature class (or something) of these barriers?
Thanks!
katie

Answer (score 1):

you need to use [Trace Geometric Network (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000015r000000) Geoprocessioning tool and choose your barriers features as a barrier layer input

[image]